# Error That Are Not Really Errors In Python

Tags: python, syntax-error

Now my program says:  `unindent does not match any other indentation level`.  The section looks like this:

```
if wait2 == "Four":
                print("You Have Waited For Four Months")
                money += (population * 6)
                time.sleep(1.5)
                print("From The Rent You Now Have $" + str(money) + " In Total")
```

Comment: Please include the full error message.

Comment: Please show the actual traceback and error message, along with the line before the one you show.

Comment: Maybe you have an unmatched `(` or `[` before this block

Comment: The error is just a pop up box saying:  Syntax Error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a closing `)` on this line, You can fix it by adding a closing parenthesis or by removing the opening parenthesis:

```
population -= (random.randint(1, 3))
                                   ^
                                   |
```

Comment: Thank You!!! I thought my whole program was doomed!  I am planning to publish this with py2exe

Comment: Wait now my program says: unindent does not match any other indentation level

Comment: The code that is messed up looks like this:

Comment: if wait2 == "Four":
                print("You Have Waited For Four Months")
                money += (population * 6)
                time.sleep(1.5)
                print("From The Rent You Now Have $" + str(money) + " In Total")

Comment: Let me just edit my question and show you

Comment: @EthanBacon your code works fine on my system, use 4 spaces for indentation.

Comment: Well I will just have to see

Comment: @EthanBacon see http://ideone.com/tAbIkt, it works fine.

Comment: Did you make that public?!

Comment: Sorry accidentally put an !

Comment: @EthanBacon I've deleted it from ideone.

Answer (score 0):

Before the line that says

```
if wait2 == "Four":
```

You have a missing `)` in

```
population -= (random.randint(1, 3)
```